# Finding Elements in a Redrawn DOM

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium

We have a website which has a wijmo grid in it. I am attempting to test this website. In IE the grid is drawn, yet when I go into the "Developer Tools", the grid is not actually there. This makes running Selenium tests very difficult as Selenium cannot find it either.

Has anyone run into this before? If so, how do I successfully run my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is working now. The Developer had a pre-loader which was causing the problem. Once that was disabled it is now able to find the elements.

Comment: +1 Good to know it's working. Don't forget you can accept your own answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The grid *will* be part of the DOM and you should be able to select it successfully with the correct path using Selenium.

I believe it is the tools that are misleading and are simply not updating when the DOM changes.

I would try checking another browser, for example Google Chrome (<kbd>F12</kbd> in Windows). In my experience the IE Developer Tools are not as powerful or feature rich as the Chrome tools. The Chrome tools *do* update the DOM when elements are manipulated.

Comment: The items are found correctly in Firefox and Chrome. IE is the only one which cannot find anything, no matter what I am trying to find. I even built in a 45 sec wait so the page would for sure be loaded. It still cannot find the wijmo grid or anything in it, once the table has been loaded.

Comment: Hmmm, which version of IE are you using? There is a refresh button which should refresh the DOM. Does the grid show after refreshing?

Comment: It is IE9. Same results after refreshing.

Comment: I found that if I refresh the page twice that the elements are there. However, if I attempt to do a driver.navigate().refresh() The test suddenly cannot locate the browser. The error in Eclipse says "Unable to Get Browser"

Comment: Hmmm, for needing a double refresh I suspect there are multiple page updates that require an IE9 refresh in order for the DOM to properly reflect the change. As for the other error, maybe [selenium #4147](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4147) or [selenium #4138](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4138) might help.